# Reset Windows 10 to factory state without creating new user

Tags: windows-10, restore, system-restore, reset, system-recovery

I bought a Dell laptop that I find to slow.
I wanted to clean it  and return it so I proceeded with the factory reset option. My aim was to remove user account, language packs and return the laptop in the state I got (letting the next owner install the system from scratch).
It took several hour and there was no point at which I could suspend the process. Further more the installation picked up the previously installed languages
Is there a way to achieve my goal? The Dell came as windows 8.1 upgradable to Windows 10 with no installation CDs.
thanks

Comment: You can either download a Windows 8.1 ISO and simply not complete the setup and this will get you to the standard "Out of the Box" experience.  You can also use the "Reset this PC" feature within the Settings UWP application and "Choose to keep nothing"  You can also "Fresh Start" which will reinstall Windows 10.  Fresh Start can be found in Windows Defender Security Center.  There is no user in the default factory state and but based on what you describe you have no users.  Honestly I would just delete the partitions, then install the current version of Windows 10 (1709) and call it a day.

Comment: This cannot be solved without either logging in and using the features within Windows or reinstalling Windows 10/8.1.  ISOs can be downloaded for free directly from Microsoft.  However, your question is currently "too broad" to answer because I am not sure what feature you actually want to use.  You need to narrow down and tell us precisely what you want to do.

Comment: I want to return it and let the new owner install the system himself. Because of this I don't think I can  download an ISO and install the system from it as it will require some licence code later.
I thought I removed other languages I had installed but the bundles were still picked up during the new set up and they were available as an option to continue the set up in the other language.
Is there a safe point at which I can just turn off the machine and let another person finish the install?

Comment: “as it will require some licence code later.” I see you failed to read my comment completely and/or any of my answers on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 because if you had you would know this wouldn’t be a problem.  Since you still have not clarified your question I still cannot answer it.

Comment: I did read your comment. In the fist part you are taking too many shortcut and regarding the second - the fact an iso can be downloaded for free doesn't mean that the installation and usage is for free. Last time I had to deal with Windows was in the times of Vista. UX hasn't changed since then. I discovered that I can remove languages  with lpksetup. The "settings" seem to only hide it.

Comment: “the fact an iso can be downloaded for free doesn't mean that the installation and usage is for free.” You have a license.  How does this apply to you?  What does removing language packs have to do with your question?  Format the HDD, install Windows 10, when you get to the point of creating account just turn off the device

Comment: Are you talking about returning it to the store where you bought it?   A big chain store?   I would imagine that they have a procedure for wiping and reloading any PC that they resold after it was returned.  If they didn’t, imagine the liability problem they would have if you returned a PC loaded with malware and they resold it as-is.